# why callback from custom hook never see component props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I cannot find how to solve one issue could anyone help

wrote simple hook for catching shortcuts but callback from that custom hook doesn't see new props in component

```
export const useShortcut = (key, isAlt = false, callback) => {
  function onKeyPressed(event) {
    if (event.key.toLowerCase() === key && event.altKey === isAlt) {
      callback();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPressed);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyPressed);
    };
  }, []);
};

export const MyComponent = (props) => {
  function handleShortcut() {
    if (props.prop1) {
      //???prop1 came from parent and components tab tell me but from shortcut hook it always null
    }
  }

  useShortcuts("n", true, () => handleShortcut());

  return <div></div>;
};
```

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPressed);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyPressed);
  };
}, []);
```

Because of the empty dependency array, you are only setting up the listener once, using whatever `onKeyPressed` exists on the first render. That function closes over `props` from the first render, and it will never update.

Simplest fix for this is just to remove the dependency array, so the effect runs every time:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPressed);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyPressed);
  };
});
```

Now when the component renders, it will tear down the old listener and create a new one with the new copy of `onKeyPressed`. That new function sees the new `props`.

---

Hypothetically, if setting up and tearing down the listeners was an expensive operation (it's not), then you could limit it to only happen when `onKeyPressed` changes, by putting `onKeyPressed` into the dependency array. However, this needs to be accompanied by using `useCallback` to make sure `onKeyPressed` doesn't change unless it needs to.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPressed);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyPressed);
  };
}, [onKeyPressed]);

// used like:
export const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const handleShortcut = useCallback(function () {
    if (props.prop1) {
      // ...
    }
  }, [props.prop1]);

  useShortcuts("n", true, handleShortcut);
```